# imagecreatefromjpeg no muestra imagen en PHP

Tags: php, php5

Buenas, tengo una pagina .php con el siguiente código:

```
<?php

        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

        $im_orig=imagecreatefromjpeg("https://drupal-multisite-s3.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/files/universo.1.jpg");
        $im_dest=imagecreatefromjpeg("https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/images/wallpaper/PIA09579-800x600.jpg");
        $im_dest_x=110;
        $im_dest_y=60;
        $im_orig_x=0;
        $im_orig_y=0;
        $im_orig_w=240;
        $im_orig_h=180;
        $im_orig_nw=100;
        $im_orig_nh=75;

        imagecopyresampled($im_dest, $im_orig, $im_dest_x, $im_dest_y, $im_orig_x, $im_orig_y, $im_orig_w, $im_orig_h, $im_orig_nw, $im_orig_nh);

        imagejpeg($im_dest);
        imagedestroy($im_dest);
        imagedestroy($im_orig);

    ?>
```

Pero al cargar la pagina, solo me muesta un cuadrado pequeño y blanco con un fondo gris. Inspecciono el elemento, y si bien me crea la etiqueta  me pone como src "http://localhost/subida/" que es la carpeta donde yo tengo mi archivo php. He probado usar imagenes que se encuentren en la misma carpeta que mi archivo, por ej

```
$im_orig=imagecreatefromjpeg("original.jpg");
$im_dest=imagecreatefromjpeg("destino.jpg");
```

Pero el resultado es el mismo, cuadrado blanco con fondo gris y el source apuntando a la carpeta donde están los archivos.

Gracias desde ya.

Comment: Al abrir el archivo de la forma que me comenta todo el código php sale como comentado, incluso cuando mi archivo tiene la extensión php y xamp esta corriendo.

Comment: Si cambio esto asi header('Content-Type: text/html'); me salen MUCHOS simbolos raros, pero la pagina carga. Si lo dejo como el codigo de mi pregunta, al inspeccionar la consola me sale "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/jpg: "http://localhost/subida/index.php". He intentado todo lo que dicen las respuestas acerca de esto y nada me ha servido.

Comment: Por supuesto http://imgur.com/33lXWcl

Comment: Aqui se la adjunto: http://imgur.com/essuNL9

Comment: Ambas muestran lo mismo, ya que al entrar a /subida me carga directamente mi index.php. Y ambas muestran la primera imagen que pase. Fondo gris con un cuadrado blanco.

Comment: La imagen que publicaste primero, muestra código `HTML`, imagino que es el contenido del archivo `index.html` y no el `index.php`. Para mi que siempre te esta cargando el `.html` y no el `.php`